# Processing: Efficiently create uniform grid

Tags: image, processing

I'm trying to create a grid of an image (in the way one would tile a background with).  Here's what I've been using:

```
PImage bgtile;
PGraphics bg;
int tilesize = 50;

void setup() {
  
  int t = millis();
  
  fullScreen(P2D);
  background(0);
  
  bgtile = loadImage("bgtile.png");
  int bgw = ceil( ((float) width) / tilesize) + 1;
  int bgh = ceil( ((float) height) / tilesize) + 1;
  
  
  
  bg = createGraphics(bgw*tilesize,bgh*tilesize);
  bg.beginDraw();
  for(int i = 0; i < bgw; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < bgh; j++){
      bg.image(bgtile, i*tilesize, j*tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
    }
  }
  bg.endDraw();
  
  print(millis() - t);
 
}
```

The timing code says that this takes about a quarter of a second, but by my count there's a full second once the window opens before anything shows up on screen (which should happen as soon as draw is first run).  Is there a faster way to get this same effect?  (I want to avoid rendering `bgtile` hundreds of times in the draw loop for obvious reasons)

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to make use of the GPU and let [OpenGL repeat a texture](https://open.gl/textures) for you.
Processing makes it fairly easy to repeat a texture via [`textureWrap(REPEAT)`](https://processing.org/reference/textureWrap_.html)

Instead of drawing an image you'd make your own quad [shape](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html) and instead of calling `vertex(x, y)` for example, you'd call [`vertex(x, y, u, v);`](https://processing.org/reference/vertex_.html) passing texture coordinates (more low level info on the OpenGL link above). The simple idea is x,y would control the geometry on screen and u,v would control how the texture is applied to the geometry.

Another thing you can control is [`textureMode()`](https://processing.org/reference/textureMode_.html) which allows you control how you specify the texture coordinates (U, V):

- `IMAGE` mode is the default: you use pixel coordinates (based on the dimensions of the texture)
- `NORMAL` mode uses values between 0.0 and 1.0 (also known as normalised values) where 1.0 means the maximum the texture can go (e.g. image width for U or image height for V) and you don't need to worry about knowing the texture image dimensions

Here's a basic example based on the `textureMode()` example above:

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  fullScreen(P2D);
  noStroke();
  img = loadImage("https://processing.org/examples/moonwalk.jpg");
  // texture mode can be IMAGE (pixel dimensions) or NORMAL (0.0 to 1.0)
  // normal means 1.0 is full width (for U) or height (for V) without having to know the image resolution 
  textureMode(NORMAL);
  // this is what will make handle tiling for you
  textureWrap(REPEAT);
}
void draw() {
  // drag mouse on X axis to change tiling
  int tileRepeats = (int)map(constrain(mouseX,0,width), 0, width, 1, 100);
  // draw a textured quad
  beginShape(QUAD);
  // set the texture 
  texture(img);
  //     x    , y     , U          , V
  vertex(0    , 0     , 0          , 0);
  vertex(width, 0     , tileRepeats, 0);
  vertex(width, height, tileRepeats, tileRepeats);
  vertex(0    , height, 0          , tileRepeats);
  endShape();
  text((int)frameRate+"fps",15,15);
}
```

Drag the mouse on the Y axis to control the number of repetitions.

In this simple example both vertex coordinates and texture coordinates are going clockwise (top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left order).

[image: moonwalk demo opengl tiling 3x3]

[image: moonwalk demo opengl tiling many times]

There are probably other ways to achieve the same result: using a [PShader](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/) comes to mind.

Your approach caching the tiles in setup is ok.
Even flattening your nested loop into a single loop at best may only shave a few milliseconds off, but nothing substantial.
If you tried to cache my snippet above it would make a minimal difference.

In this particular case, because of the back and forth between Java/OpenGL (via JOGL), as far as I can tell using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/), it looks like there's not a lot of room for improvement since simply swapping buffers takes so long (e.g. `bg.image()`):

[image: visualvm profiling PGraphics image()]

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to use processing's built in `get();` which saves a PImage of the coordinates you pass, for example: `PImage pic = get(0, 0, width, height);` will capture a "screenshot" of your entire window. So, you can create the image like you already are, and then take a screenshot and display that screenshot.

```java
PImage bgtile;
PGraphics bg;
PImage screenGrab;
int tilesize = 50;

void setup() {
    fullScreen(P2D);
    background(0);

    bgtile = loadImage("bgtile.png");
    int bgw = ceil(((float) width) / tilesize) + 1;
    int bgh = ceil(((float) height) / tilesize) + 1;

    bg = createGraphics(bgw * tilesize, bgh * tilesize);
    bg.beginDraw();
    for (int i = 0; i < bgw; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bgh; j++) {
            bg.image(bgtile, i * tilesize, j * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
        }
    }
    bg.endDraw();
    screenGrab = get(0, 0, width, height);
}

void draw() {
    image(screenGrab, 0, 0);
}
```

This will still take a little bit to generate the image, but once it does, there is no need to use the for loops again unless you change the tilesize.

@George Profenza's answer looks more efficient than my solution, but mine may take a little less modification to the code you already have.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't do anything my code doesn't - I can draw the background quickly with `image(bg)` after running the setup.

Comment: oh my goodness, your right :D I have never used createGraphics, but it makes perfect sense.