# Make p5js project run faster

Tags: javascript, paint, p5.js

I made a project called "pixel paint" by javascript with p5js library, but when I run it, that project ran too slow. I don't know why and how to make it run faster. And here is my code:

```js
let h = 40, w = 64;
let checkbox;
let scl = 10;
let painting = new Array(h);
let brush = [0, 0, 0];
for(let i = 0; i < h; i++) {
  painting[i] = new Array(w);
  for(let j = 0; j < w; j++) {
    painting[i][j] = [255, 255, 255];
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(w * scl, h * scl);
  checkbox = createCheckbox('Show gird line', true);
  checkbox.changed(onChange);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  for(let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for(let x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      fill(painting[y][x]);
      rect(x * scl, y * scl, scl, scl);
    }
  }

  if(mouseIsPressed) {
    paint();
  }
}

function onChange() {
  if (checkbox.checked()) {
    stroke(0);
  } else {
    noStroke();
  }
}

function paint() {
  if(mouseX < w * scl && mouseY < h * scl) {
    let x = floor(mouseX / scl);
    let y = floor(mouseY / scl);
    painting[y][x] = brush;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Include-->
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

**Is there a solution to make my project run faster?**

Comment: Too slow? The provided example runs quite nicely, I wouldn't expect it to run faster than that. There has to be something else in your real code slowing down. Or you've to elaborate what exactly you think is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is easy to read.

It might not be worth optimising at this stage as it would make the code potentially needlessly more complex/harder to read and change in the future.

If you want to learn about different ways you could achieve the same thing I can provide a few ideas, though, for your particular use case int terms of performance might won't make a huge difference:

1. Instead of using the `painting` as a nested `[w][h]` array you could use a flat `[w * h]` array and use a single `for` loop instead of a nested for loop. This would be somewhat similar to using [`pixels[]`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/pixels). (You can convert x,y to an index (`index = x + (y * width)`) and the other way around(`x = index % width, y = floor(index / width)`)
2. You could in theory use a `p5.Image`, access `pixels[]` to draw into it and render using `image()` (ideally you'd get lower level access to the WebGL renderer to enable [antialiasing](https://github.com/PixelsCommander/isAntialiasingSupportedForWebGL) if it's supported by the browser). The grid itself could be a [`texture()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/texture) for a quad where you'd use `vertex()` to specify not only x,y geometry positions, but also u, v texture coordinates in tandem with [`textureWrap(REPEAT)`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textureWrap). (I posted an older [repeat Processing example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63080265/processing-efficiently-create-uniform-grid/63081080#63081080): the logic is the same and syntax is almost identical)
3. Similar to the `p5.Image` idea, you can cache the drawing using [`createGraphics()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics): e.g. only update the `p5.Graphics` instance when the mouse is dragged, otherwise render the cached drawing. Additionally you can make use of [`noLoop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noLoop)/[`loop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loop) to control when p5's canvas gets updated (e.g. `loop()` on [`mousePressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed), updated graphics on [`mouseMoved()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseMoved), `noLoop()` on [`mouseReleased()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseReleased))

There are probably other methods too.

While it's good to be aware of techniques to optimise your code,
I strongly recommend **not** optimising until you need to; and when you do
use a profiler (DevTools has that) to focus only the bits are the slowest
and not waste time and code readability on part of code where optimisation
wouldn't really make an impact.